# Repeat command after a period of time

Tags: command-line

I have a command like this:

```
if [ $battery_level -le 6 -a $STATUS = $NOT_CHARGING ] #Battery Low 1
        then
/usr/bin/notify-send -i "$ICONL" "Battery critically low!" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-information.oga
```

It gives a message and a sound at a certain battery level. But it repeats too often.

I can set it to sleep and run again by separating the same command with a line like `sleep 120s`, but I do not know exactly how many times should it be run.

I need it to run at an interval of two minutes, indefinitely (as at some point system sleep or hibernation is triggered by a completely different script).

Looking here: [How to Run or Repeat a Linux Command Every X Seconds Forever](http://www.tecmint.com/run-repeat-linux-command-every-x-seconds/), I see that an option is `sleep` and the other is `watch`.

`watch` seems to work but it only works with the form

`watch -n 120 <my_line>`, and that changes a bit the output (battery level is not shown) anymore.

Comment: Use `while` in place of `if` and place the whole code you show in file+make it executable. And then, just `watch -n 120 your_battery_level_indicator.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `while` loop:

```
while [ "$battery_level" -le 6 ] && [ "$STATUS" = "$NOT_CHARGING" ]
```

Comment: but then will it give any message if the level goes below 6?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean how does it update `battery_level`, simply replace it with the *command* you used to get `battery_level`